# Auto login web app through url in Lotus Domino 6.5.4?

Tags: authentication, subdomain, lotus-notes, basic-authentication

In Domino 6.5.4, is it possible to assign newly registered account user a new subdomain under our domain (eg. accountid.abc.net) and a related database(eg. accountid.nsf); so that once the user opens url(accountid.abc.net) through our email notification, he will automatically login to the server and the database accountid.nsf will be opened?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is possible. Unfortunately redirection- documents that you need for that are only applied after a http restart, so this might not be the best solution for you. 
You might find the iwaredir- template useful to do this without subdomain, but this depends on what exactly you want to achieve.

BUT: Stackoverflow is not there to do "consulting" for you about the best solution for a quite "generic" topic, but to help you with concrete questions for concrete code issues.

So this might not be the best platform for your question.